# como utilizar include_once con archivos de distinto nivel

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo utilizar la función `include` o `include_once` de php con archivos en distintos niveles de carpetas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para llamar a un archivo que esta dentro de otra carpeta se deben de utilizar las siguientes formas:

1. ../archivo.x/   'para llegar a la raiz del proyecto'
2. ./archivo.x/    'para volver una carpeta atrás de donde esta el fichero que realiza el include'
3. archivo.x       'cuando el archivo esta en la misma carpeta'
4. /carpeta/archivo.x    'cuando el archivo a llamar esta una carpeta dentro de la carpeta en la que el archivo ejecuta el include'